# How do you insert something into mysql using pdo using WHERE

Tags: php, pdo

So I am trying to change the status of something when values are met using WHERE

Code:

```
$insertstatus = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO
   csvdata (status)  VALUES ('$status') WHERE username = '".$username."'");
        $insertstatus->execute();
```

Not working.  If you could give me a hand.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: "Not Working" could mean any number of things.  What's the specific error you are getting?

Comment: Please learn how to bind parameters in prepared statements. If you write your app like this, anyone can come along and trash your whole database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the `where` clause, you need to use update. From the looks of it, you are trying to update anyhow as you are only using one column from your table.

```
$insertstatus = $DBH->prepare("update
   csvdata set status=  '$status' WHERE username = '".$username."'");
    $insertstatus->execute();
```

As PeeHaa correctly points out though, using a prepared statement with parameters would be a slight change in your code, and a better option for you. You can do it like this:

```
$sql="update csvdata set status=:status where username=:username";
$sth=$DBH->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array(':status' => $status, ':username' => $username));
```

This way you are preparing the statement so the database *knows* what will happen. You then pass the variables to the database via the `execute()` function in an array.

Comment: Why use PDO exactly like `mysql_*`?

Comment: `$insertstatus = $DBH->prepare("update
   csvdata set status = ? WHERE username = ?");
    $insertstatus->execute(array($status,$username));` is binding correct?

Comment: @PeeHaa It's the crack of dawn here, I haven't even had my coffee and then by the time I write it all down, my post has been editied twice already. I love this place :)

Comment: @DavidBiga You can bind params individually or just pass them in an array. In my edit I used named params which might be easier to read/troubleshoot.

Comment: @Fluffeh my mail function is not working properly you think you could give me a hand I am using the `mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);`

Comment: @DavidBiga Sure pop another question up with the relevant code (I can't do anything with just that snippet) and we can have a look at it.